# vim how transfer :substitute command to script

Tags: html, vim

Here are 2 :s commands.  Work fine at command line or as part of a key mapping, but I cannot get them to run correctly in a vim script.  I've used normal, execute, execute "normal..." and call normal on them.  I've put the range with the s, and before normal, I've tried them with and without a : before the s.  How should I write them within a .vim file?

```
:%s/<[\/]\?SPAN\|DIV\|OPTION[^>]*>//gi
:%s/<\(hr\|h[1-6]\|ul\|li\|p\|tt\|ol\|table\|tr\|td\|p\) [^>]\+/<\1/gi
```

Comment: I'm not sure if these are possible in scripts but there's always `substitute()` function with a very similar usage to these and intended to be used in scripts.

Comment: @gokcehan: `substitute()` is for variable contents, you can still use `:substitute` if you want to modify the current buffer.

Comment: @IngoKarkat isn't `:substitute` just an abbrev for `:s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just add them to a script. You don’t have to prefix them with anything in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can put Ex commands like yours into a `myscript.vim` file, then execute the commands via

```
:source myscript.vim
```

This should work without modifications (you don't need the leading `:`, but it doesn't hurt). I don't see any problems, and you don't need `:execute` unless you want to include variables. `:normal` is for normal-mode commands (like `diw`, for example).

Typically, you'd place those custom commands into a function, though (which would be placed in `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/plugin/myscript.vim`), and invoke it via `:call`, either directly, via a mapping, or custom command.

Comment: Many thanks.  I'd first assumed they would work directly in a .vim file, but found I had to do 'normal d1G' so assumed I would have to normal them all.  My vimrc is overloaded with keymappings, so I've started transferring lengthy ones to .vim files.